# AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'load_data'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am engaging a project now, and the library utils might be frequently used. However, I encounter a problem

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import featuretools as ft
import utils

data_path = 'dataturbo/train_FD003.txt'
data = utils.load_data(data_path)
data.head()
```

how to solve this guys, i'm always encountering this problem

Comment: What's in `utils` (try a `dir(utils)`)? Do you have a utils.py file in your working folder?

Comment: yes i have it in my working folder

Comment: You have _a_ "utils.py" in your working folder, that may or may not have a `load_data` function? Or you have _the correct_ "utils.py" in your working folder, that does have a `load_data` function? If you installed it with pip or something, it probably installed to your Python installation folder, not whatever folder you're using for the programs you write. If you have a "utils.py" in the same folder as your program, and it isn't the right one, you'll get this error.

Comment: thx i have solved the problem :)

Comment: What was the solution? I'm dealing with the same issue after installing `utils` with anaconda

Answer (score -1):

For those who wants to know the solution. I believe he is testing a package from FeatureTools.

https://github.com/Featuretools/predict-remaining-useful-life

`import utils` package is not something you install from conda or pip install, but a utils.py script you can download from FeatureTools github page.